Why is this question being closed?
This question is receiving a lot of close votes (3 at of this moment), but I am not sure I understand why. Of course it is not very well written, but I think it can be turned into a valuable resource. Can someone explain to me why would someone vote to close instead of suggesting an edit?

My reason for closing such a question is perfectly encapsulated in one of the standard motivation:

primarily opinion-based
  Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

There are tons of methods, websites, apps, guidebooks, schools etc. to learn Italian, from browsing an old-fashioned grammar to come to Italy and live here, learning just by having to. In fact, there are tons of categories of ways to learn (courses, full immersion, self-teaching, programs).
We couldn't even hope to list a significant fraction of them (not even, say, for a single category), much less so asses their relative merits and faults. What would happen, in the best case, is that a handful of people would tell about their own favourite or most loathed course, website or book, which is exactly how not to tackle seriously (let me say, scientifically) a question.
In movies.SE one would receive a cold response if, say, they asked to be suggested a good James Bond movie, but at least it would be quite feasible to list all of them. Here somebody is asking about a good movie.

I think I disagree with this. It is true that we cannot hope to catalog all resources for learning Italian, but exactly since there are so many of them, we should be able to give some general guidelines, with pluses and minuses for each approach and maybe some examples. While this question is certainly in part opinion-based, so are most interesting questions after all.

@DenisNardin: «While this question is certainly in part opinion-based, so are most interesting questions after all»: of course, and whole areas of culture arise around them, but they are not suitable for the SE format, which in fact explicitly discourages them.

I totally understand where you are coming from, but this is a matter of degree and judgment. I think we are being a little too restrictive on this particular question. I only have experience about Mathoverflow and there this kind of question is generally well received. See for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239858/text-for-studying-group-representations-in-the-context-of-abstract-harmonic-an https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228624/book-recommendation-for-cobordism-theory https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218797/notes-on-flag-varieties-and-grassmannians-for-beginners

"List" and "advice" questions are frowned on at most SE sites because they are too "personal," that is, they require a great deal of personal, as opposed to general, knowledge to answer.
Italian SE allows less leeway in these matters than some of the other sites I've been on.
